# How to POST NULL value C#

Tags: c#, php, webclient, namevaluecollection

I need to POST data from C# WinForms application into PHP page. I'm using WebClient with sample code below:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
    values.Add("menu_parent", null);

    string URL = "http://192.168.20.152/test.php";
    byte[] response = client.UploadValues(URL, values);

    string responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);

    MessageBox.Show(responseString);
}
```

On the PHP side, I'm doing simple IF condition to test whether the `menu_parent` is NULL or not with this very simplified code:

```
<?php
$parent = $_POST['menu_parent'];

if ($parent === null)
    echo "menu_parent is null";
else
    echo "menu_parent is: <".$parent.">"; // This prints out.

if (is_null($parent))
    echo "menu_parent is also null";
else
    echo "menu_parent is also: <".$parent.">" // This also prints out.

if ($parent === "")
    echo "menu_parent is empty string"; // This also prints out.
else
    echo "menu_parent is not empty";
?>
```

The problem is the `NULL` value of `menu_parent` is converted into empty string in the PHP page. I've checked the [MSDN page about WebClient.UploadValues method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900ted1f(v=vs.110).aspx) and also [NameValueCollection class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx). The page said that `NULL` value are accepted. How to POST null value? Is `NULL` value is unacceptable in this case?

Comment: Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php and this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php. And decide which one is best for you.

Comment: a http semantic which relies on the difference between `String.Empty` and `(string)null` is worth reconsidering. why do you need to distringuish here? if the parent is set, then it will have a non-zerolength name/identifier, otherwise it is empty?

Comment: @hungrykoala The actual code includes ISSET function. I'm sorry i forgot add this function on the question.

Comment: HTTP is a textual protocol so null doesn't exist in that context. It's either an empty string or not existing

Comment: [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is a boolean function so it will return either TRUE or FALSE. You're using it wrong in your case.

Comment: @dlatikay I have to treat every value that user posted, including NULL value. The business rule allow user to post NULL value. In this case, NULL and empty string are two different values that I have to treat differently.

Comment: @hungrykoala Pardon me. I've edit the wrong line. But the actual code already use the ISSET function. This is the simplified code.

Comment: one possible solution is to introduce a second argument which is a flag indicating whether the value of the payload is null or not. or as others suggest, use the absence of a key to indicate NULL

Comment: @apokryfos If so, is there any other way to POST null value from user? Or maybe doesn't need to POST at all and use different logic on PHP?

Comment: I would suggest you to pass values in JSON format to the PHP script, this is the best way to share share data to the third party applications including API's for iOS and Android...later you can use JSON decode to fetch values for the keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP protocol is a textual protocol and therefore you can't really send a "null" value.

Assuming you're using the [JSON.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library (though there's probably equivalent ways to do this built-in).

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string,object> { { "menu_parent",null } }; 
    var parameterJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json"); 

    string URL = "http://192.168.20.152/test.php";
    byte[] response = client.UploadData(URL, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameterJson));

    string responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);

    MessageBox.Show(responseString);
}
```

Then in PHP you can do:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
if ($data->menu_parent === null) {
   //should work
}
```

Comment: Your sample code is working, although the method .UploadValues should be changed to .UploadData, because UploadValues takes NameValueCollection argument and not byte[]. Your sample code and Mangesh Sathe's comment are basically the same (using JSON format). I already used Json.NET for another case, and this code works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I always use a data model and send it as object in C# after deserialization-serialization with JsonConvert class. Then in PHP, I always get it as object and convert it to related model again. So there is no NULL key-value loss. But "NameValueCollection" has equal data model in PHP(?), I don't know.